# Deleting complete Ubuntu partition by Windows 7 disk

Tags: ubuntu, uninstall

I installed Ubuntu 12.4 version on my Dell desktop and I want to delete Ubuntu completely and install a fresh version of Windows 7.

I have tried googling but didn't find the proper information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Legally reinstall the original windows](http://superuser.com/questions/160597/legally-reinstall-the-original-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you want to delete ubuntu, right ? Well, for one that loves Ubuntu I see no reason in deleting it but anyway. [Here is a post on the AskUbuntu forum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on) that I think could help.

[This is another post that I think could also help you](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154661/how-to-uninstall-ubuntu-12-04-lts-installed-alongside-win-7-from-boot-cd)

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you will have ONLY Windows forever, then you might just delete all existing partitions (or keep the recovery one, if you have and want) and automatically create a partition in the new unallocated space. Windows 7 installer will setup everything accordingly and you are good to go!

Comment: he needs to fix MBR too

Comment: He shouldn't have any problems as the installer will fix MBR after creating partitions. I have never had any problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention a fresh install of windows and to fully remove Ubuntu, there are no special considerations other than "back up the data you want to keep before proceeding".

Then all you need to do is put in your recovery/install disc (or boot from the recovery partition, if you have it built in and didn't remove it). Then during setup, format and delete all partitions (if you have a recovery partition, then don't format or delete that partition). Then install. MBR should be automatically installed and you'll just have a clean windows install (I'm assuming a single hard drive, multiple hard discs changes things).

Answer (score 0):

What does " install a fresh version of Windows 7. " mean?

Do you mean

FIRST. Uninstall Ubuntu as if it had not been installed.

Or

SECOND. Uninstall Windows and Ubuntu and then install Windows 7

Or

THIRD. You have Ubuntu installed only and want to uninstall it and install Windows 7

## For FIRST situation

There are many methods to do this, here I post one of them:

### Tools you need

1. Ubuntu LiveCD; Other Linux LiveCD is also ok
2. Windwos 7 Install Disc

### Steps( Skip if unnecessary)

1. Backup your data: If you have ever stored any private data on Ubuntu:

   - Boot into Ubuntu
   - Mount any Windows partition
   - Move All your data
2. Unistall Ubuntu

   - Boot into Ubuntu LiveCD
   - Open GParted
   - Delete Ubuntu partition (Usually, there should be two)
   - Fully make use of those free space

     1. Create new partition (NTFS or FAT32, NTFS recommanded)
     2. OR extend existing partition
     3. ** This could be easily done with GParted
3. Fix bootloader

   - Boot into Windows Install Disc
   - Click `Repair your computer`
   - Choose the Windows you installed
   - Get to `Command Prompt`
   - Enter

     > bootrec /fixmbr
     >
     > bootrec /fixboot
4. That should be done.

## For SECOND situation

### Tools you need

1. Windows 7 Install Disc

### Steps

1. Backup

   - If you have any external storage device: Move all the files you need to keep( Both on Windows and Ubuntu) to that device
   - If you don't have one: Move all the files you want to keep out of both Windows System Partition( Usually C:) and Ubuntu partition
2. Install Windows

   - Boot into Windows 7 Install Disc
   - Just follow its guide( Maybe you have to format your Windows System Firstly)
3. That's done

## For THIRD situation

### Tools you need

It depends

If you have external storage devices:

- Windows 7 Install Disc

If you don't have one:

- Ubuntu LiveCD OR other Linux LiveCD

### Steps - If you have external storage devices

1. Boot into Ubuntu copy all data you want to keep out to your external storage devices
2. Boot into Windows 7 Install Disc
3. Format the whole disk and install Windows 7

### Setps - If you have not external storage devices

1. Boot into Ubuntu LiveCD
2. Use GParted to create a new NTFS/FAT partition
3. Move your data to that partition
4. Reboot to Windows 7 Install Disc
5. Delete Ubuntu partition and install Windows 7

Hope this quick tutorial help. Please feel free to tell me if you need more help.